# No service endpoints found:

Tags: wcf, endpoint

I am following MSDN tutorial to create WCF Service. I did my first three steps and after that, while compiling GettingStrtedHost I get the error

```
The service cannot be started. This service has no endpoint defined. Please add at least one endpoint for the service in config file and try again.
```

But I defined the endpoint..

```
selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new WSHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");
```

I didn't change the name of the project as it was suggested in related posts. Please help me:)

**EDIT1:**

The code for ICalculator is:

```
namespace GettingStartedLib
{
   [ServiceContract(Namespace="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
    public interface ICalculator
    {
       [OperationContract]
       double Add(double n1, double n2);
       [OperationContract]
       double Substract(double n1, double n2);
       [OperationContract]
       double Multiply(double n1, double n2);
       [OperationContract]
       double Divide(double n1, double n2);
    }  
}
```

**EDIT2:**

```
Configuration File:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="GettingStartedLib.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/GettingStartedLib/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="GettingStartedLib.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: did you mark the interface with `ServiceContract` and the end point as `OperationContract`

Comment: I marked the interface with `ServiceContract` but why would I do the same to endpoint? I mean only methods in the interface are marked wih `OperationContract`. I've only written:

 `selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new WSHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");`

Comment: Please add the code for `ICalculator`

Comment: Did you add the correct setting into the app.config file and ensured that the name match the namespaces used in you application

Comment: I never changed app.config file because it wasn't said in the tutorial. I just updated my question to show how it is created by default. I guess names are ok.

Comment: Okay, u were right. It was the point, I didn't realize it, because VS. NET didn't give me warnings though.. Thanks!!

Comment: Yet I have another question:) Why if I added the line:

`Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted");`
and then:

`ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), baseAddress);`

it still load the baseAddress that is set by default in *.config file?